# How to extract a pattern of multiple lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, html

I am wondering how to extract a pattern of multiple lines, especially when this pattern is repeating in the text.

The text looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td>Wife</td>
<td>Pilialo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Wind</td>
<td>Makani Dav</td>
</tr>
...
```

the text goes on in the same format:

```
<tr>
<td>some text</td>
<td>some text2</td>
</tr>
```

I need to get the second cell within each `<tr> ... </tr>`
i.e. the output should be (if there were only the above two `<tr> ... </tr>` )

```
Pilialo
Makani Dav
```

Comment: Do you mean the second *word* or the second ***cell**?*  For example, what output do you want from ``<tr> <td>Quantity Ordered</td> <td>Unit Price</td> </tr>``?  Do you guarantee that all row data will be in data cells?  What do you want from `<tr>Misplaced Text <td>…</td></tr>`?  What about `<th>…</th>`?  What about text that’s not in a table at all?    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Obligatory reference: [You can't parse HTML with regex.  Because HTML can’t be parsed by regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/3960947 "RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your sample is contained within a valid HTML/XML document (specifically, there's a single root element), and that as G-Man said you want the second *table cell* of each row, it's easy with XMLstarlet:

```
< /tmp/xml xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//tr/td[2]' -v . -n
Pilialo
Makani
```

`sel` select from the document

`-t` here's the template:

`-m '//tr/td[2]'` match the second `td` element under a `tr` anywhere

`-v .` output the value of (text inside) the node

`-n` append a newline